# Send whole content to mail in pdf after clicking a button in jsp

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, pdf, pdf-generation

I am creating a java server page.
It has a button to send an email.
After clicking the button the  whole page content should be sent as a pdf to a client as an attachment.
I do not want to store this pdf on the server.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is the question , How to send email, or how to create a PDF ?

Comment: yes, but pdf couldn't be save in a system direcly send to client mail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use iText to generate a pdf document without having to physically create a file.

example:

```
File out = new File("somewhere.pdf");
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(new FileWriter(out)));
Document layoutDocument = new Document(pdfDocument);
layoutDocument.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
layoutDocument.close();
```

In this particular example I've used a FileWriter, but any Writer will do.
So

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(baos);

// iText logic here
...

// add bytes to email
byte[] mimeBytes = baos.toByteArray();
...
```

Check out the documentation for iText at http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples